# Using Curl command in SolrNet

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud, solrnet

curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/QNB_ARABIC/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@my_file.pdf"
this is a curl command through which we can post document to solr.
I am using it through cmd but i want to run this command through solrNet. Is there any way to post document in this way in SolrNet ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolrNet has a corresponding [Extract](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Extract.md) command that you can use for this.

Comment: HOw to extract text in string variable ?

Comment: if we put ExtractOnly=true then it will just extract the text so how to get that text in string variable.

Comment: It is not extracting text from .ott files

Comment: what is the issue and solution ?